# Confusion of proving limits

Tags: calculus, limits, epsilon-delta

Ok say we were to prove this simple limit: $\lim \limits_{x \to 2}$  $x^2$

For all epsilon > 0, there exist a delta > 0 such that  IF $ 0 < |x-2|< \delta$  THEN
$|x^2-4| < \epsilon$

We know that $|x^2-4|$ = $|x+2||x-2| < \epsilon$

Now we need to find an estimated value for $|x+2|$

Let $\delta \le 1$

$|x-2| < \delta \le 1$

So, $|x-2| < 1$

Which tells us, $1 \lt x \lt 3$

Add 2 to all sides, $3 \lt x+2 \lt 5$

The example I had looked at takes $|x+2| < 5$, Why can you not take $|x+2| \gt 3$

This step is what gets me confused, I do understand why the first case is taken rather than the second one , and I do not know how to check if the one I had taken works.

Comment: Because you want to bound it from above? You don't immediately understand every step of a $\delta-\epsilon$ proof, you slowly get used to it. I'd advice to practice a lot and it'll come naturally to you.

Comment: you always want to bound it from above?

Comment: The reason why  $|x+2| > 3$ does not work, is because if we assume that $|x^2-4| < \epsilon \implies 3|x-2| < \epsilon.$ The issue is in the symbol $\implies$, if it went the other way, then you're finished, but in this case all you've done is show a trivial implication that doesn't get you what you want, i.e setting your $\delta$ as in the  $\epsilon - \delta$ definition of the limit.

Comment: The idea is: for any interval $J = (L - \varepsilon, L + \varepsilon)$ around the limit L, no matter how small, you can find a small enough interval $I = (x - \delta, x + \delta)$ around $x$ such that $f$ sends every point of $I$ (excepting $x$) into $J$. The absolute values are just a shorthand for this.

Comment: (cont) In this case, $L =4, x = 2, f(x) = x^2$, so the condition becomes: no matter how small $\varepsilon > 0$, there's a $\delta > 0$ such that if $2 - \delta < u < 2 + \delta$ then $4 - \varepsilon < u^2 < 4 + \varepsilon$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can use the lower bound; but it is not useful here. As the definition shows, our goal is to see, given any $\varepsilon > 0$, whether we can make $|x^{2}-4| < \varepsilon$ by bounding $|x-2|$ from above in terms of $\varepsilon$; this indicates that it is best for us to bound $|x+2|$ from above. However, it is not necessary to bound $|x+2|$ in the way you are considering.

If $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then $|x^{2}-4| = |x-2||x+2|$; to bound $|x+2|$ from above, we find that for $|x-2| < 1$ we have
$
|x| - 2 \leq |x-2| < 1,
$
which implies that
$|x+2| \leq |x| + 2 < 5$,
and hence
$|x-2||x+2| < 5|x-2|$; if $\varepsilon > 0$, then $|x-2| < \varepsilon/5$ only if $5|x-2| < \varepsilon$. Combining the two upper bounds for $|x-2|$ together, we have obtained this: for every $\varepsilon > 0$, we have $|x-2| < \min \{ 1, \varepsilon/5 \}$ only if $|x^{2} - 4| < \varepsilon$.

I hope the above somewhat helps.